# Как вытащить текст со Html странички? Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, .net, htmlagilitypack

Всё очень просто как вытащить текст с Html странички с помощью Html Agility Pack?
К примеру у нас есть страничка того же сайта

1. Html Agility Pack

:
[html-agility-pack.net](https://html-agility-pack.net/), и нам к примеру нужна втащить текст количества скачиваний вопрос как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ищешь ноду по нужному и уникальному xpath (нету таких же элементов по такому же xpath) и вытаскиваешь с нее Value или innerHtml

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc= new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

string name = htmlDoc
                .DocumentNode
                .SelectNodes("некий xpath")
                .First()
                .Value;
```

Попытайся задавать более конкретный вопрос в следующий раз.